# How to add images in Protege

Tags: annotations, owl, ontology, protege

How can I describe class instances with images (e.g. abc.png) and display them inside Protege 5.2.0? I have read the tutorial which uses widgets, but the Forms tab is no longer available in current version of Protege-Owl.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project which intends to provide such ontology : [Schema.org](http://schema.org/ImageObject).
It is also possible to fully describe a picture thank to the use a of metadata ontology (ISO, ...).

`schema:image` annotation property may provide what you intend to do.

Answer (score 1):

For [annotation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Annotation_Properties) values that are URLs that point to images, Protégé displays thumbnails of the images.

[image: Annotation property value]

More info: https://github.com/protegeproject/protege/issues/315.

**Update**

You should add the `schema:image` annotation property (or another [suitable](https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms?q=image&type=property) annotation property) first:

[image: annotation property views]

Answer (score 1):

You can add pictures both for classes and instances.
Be aware until this moment you only can add picture from the web.
I'm going to show you how to add a picture for a class.
First go to Annotation tab and click on + button:

[image]

A window will be opened. At this window, you should add `schema:image` as an annotation property:

[image]

After adding `schema:image`, go to **IRI Editor** tab at the same window and paste the picture URL into the box (for copying the picture URL, right-click on the image on the web and then click on **copy image address**):

[image]

By clicking on OK you can see the thumbnail of the picture:

[image]

Now if you click on this thumbnail, the full image will be opened in a new tab in your browser and you can see it in full size.